# AWS elastic beanstalk : installing libreoffice on deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to have LibreOffice installed on my web server. Since I'm using autoscaling with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I need to install it on deployment. To do so, I am using .ebextensions files, but can't get it to work. This is my config file in .ebextensions folder:

```
commands:
  01-download-libreoffice:
    command: wget http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/6.0.2/rpm/x86_64/LibreOffice_6.0.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz
  02-untar:
    command: sudo tar -xvf LibreOffice_6.0.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz
  03-install:
    command: |
      if [ ${APP_ENV} == "production" ]; then
        cd LibreOffice_6.0.2.1_Linux_x86-64_rpm/RPMS
        sudo yum localinstall *.rpm
      fi
  04-symlink:
    command: sudo ln -fs /opt/libreoffice6.0/program/soffice /usr/bin/soffice
```

I tried to run these commands myself on my ec2-instance one after another as the root user, and everything worked. Only thing I might suspect: when I run the localinstall command, I need to confirm (there is a [y/n] prompt) to start the installation.

If this was the problem, I think I would still find a zipped LibreOffice file on my server or even untared LibreOffice files, but I can't find anything when I ssh into the ec2 instance after deployment.

There is no error message on deployment. Also, I can see that other .ebextensions scripts are running fine since some processes are running as asked in these scripts.

Any idea where the problem could be?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Konrad Yes. I just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it can be of any help, here is how I manage to install Libreoffice on my EC2 instances on deployment. This will install libreoffice 5.4 in /opt/libreoffice5.4

The following code is placed in this file : .ebextensions/01-libreoffice-setup.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    libXinerama.x86_64: []
    cups-libs: []
    dbus-glib: []
commands:
  01-download-libreoffice:
    command: wget http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/5.4.6/rpm/x86_64/LibreOffice_5.4.6_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz
    cwd: /tmp
    test: "[ ! -f /tmp/LibreOffice_5.4.6_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz ]"
  02-untar:
    command: sudo tar -xvf LibreOffice_5.4.6_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz
    cwd: /tmp
    test: "[ ! -d /tmp/LibreOffice_5.4.6.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm ]"
  03-install:
    command: sudo yum localinstall *.rpm -y
    cwd: /tmp/LibreOffice_5.4.6.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm/RPMS
    test: "[ ! -d /opt/libreoffice5.4 ]"
```

Comment: I also had to add `cairo` as a yum package when I installed LibreOffice_6.4.